# Flutter android app build release variant doesnt include assets in the res directory but debug and profile do, what is the difference?

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, push-notification

I am new to flutter development, When i build my android project in release, the assets of the res folder are not included and the notification icons are missing, i have searched for an answer but couldnt find anything specific for differences between the two build configs,

Is there a place in android manifest or build gradle that needs to be configured for the release build to include the res assets? mipmap / drawable

thank you any help is appreciated!

[image]

here is the folder tree, pretty sure the debug is using the assets in mipmap and not drawable. there was an identicle folder called release with the same android manifest as profile however did not make a difference, thanks for the help

flutter version 3.0.4

dart version 2.17.5

[image]

the files are present in both mipmap and drawable folders

Comment: Can you add your folder tree structure of notification icon placed.

Comment: added in the question body thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You `ic_notification_studio.png` should be under `res/drawable-{dpi}`.
Flutter reads the given in `AndroidInitializationSettings('ic_notification_studio')` from drawable resources.

Comment: the notification icon is already present in both the mipmaps and the drawables, for some reason only build with debug and with profile mode the icons are showing, with release its just a white square in place of the notification icon, thank you for the help

Comment: Yeah, I got your problem, Which phone you are using?

Comment: it doesnt seem to matter which phone, im testing on an android emulator from android studio android API 33, also happing on other devices ive tested galaxy s22, dont think this issue is with the device its probably something small in a config file about build settings for release

Comment: There are criteria's which based on device, the icons properties differs. But not sure with debug and release mode. Small icon should be like as transparent and and filled area. Even in png, the filled area will be converted based on status bar and theme.  https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/customize-notification-icons . Android considers the icon with filled area and transparent area.

Answer (score 0):

add this line to android manifest
 `<meta-data     android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon" android:resource="@drawable/${notificationIconAsset}" />`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).